# Css Stroke does not seem to fill for some letters

Tags: css

I have a client who is having issues on Chrome with some of the letters in a given font but not all. It appears like Chrome is rendering the stroke outline but not filling it. Has any one experienced this before? I cannot replicate it on any browser on my Mac or PC.

[See the I in this image attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YscTi.png)

Thanks!

Edit: the code I am using is as follows

```
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #333;
```

Edit 2: Updated the code to include:

```
-moz-text-stroke-color: #333;
-moz-text-stroke-width: 2px
```

We will see if it addresses any browser compatibilities issues from their end unless someone else has any idea. Will follow up when they respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use fallback fonts for chrome. since chrome has a different css rendering engine it may process that font different. 
.ttf fonts and .svg fonts are more popular in modern web designing.

here is a online font converting tool that might help.

[onlinefontconverter](https://onlinefontconverter.com/)

here is an example of how to define fallback font types in css3

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added that too and hopefully that works for them. I am unable to replicate on my end so we will see if it solves their issues.